# Appengine and GWT - feeding the python some java

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, gwt

I realize this is a dated question since appengine now comes in java, but I have a python appengine app that I want to access via GWT.  Python is just better for server-side text processing (using pyparsing of course!).  I have tried to interpret GWT's client-side RPC and that is convoluted since there is no python counterpart (python-gwt-rpc is out of date).  I just tried using JSON and RequestBuilder, but that fails when using SSL.  Does anyone have a good solution for putting a GWT frontend on a python appengine app?

Comment: JSON sounds like the best approach to me.  Can you explain further as to why this doesn't work with SSL?

Comment: JSON would be brilliant - the problem is with the RequestBuilder.  I'm actually able to use the Form widget successfully in gwt, but if I use the RequestBuilder (which almost all JSON objects are built with), it ceases to function using SSL.  Basically the request goes through, the server sends a response, but the app never receives it for some reason.  This only happens under ssl on google appengine - when reverting to plain http it works fine.  So I'm stuck with posting data to the server in forms and receiving data in hidden fields that my gwt app then grabs.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative (if you can call it that) that I'm familiar with is [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/).  Obviously, this is more of a GWT replacement than a GWT-RPC replacement.  Beyond that, I think you would be stuck with writing your own communications layer using some sort of REST-type protocol.

Comment: As for pyjamas - I like them a lot and I'm all for the idea.  I'm about 100x faster in python than java, but gwt feels like a much more robust framework.  Although I've already found some ie compatibility issues (it is not 100% cross-browser compatible - see gwt issue #3899), gwt works *very* well and is incredibly fast.  It is clear that googlers have put a bunch of quality time into this app.  I was having some issues getting pyjamas to do basic tasks.

Any more suggestions or ideas?  If I can get the RequestBuilder issue solved in SSL, that would be a *great* solution.  I'd use only JSON.

Comment: I've had good experiences using pyjamas (pyjs.org). Queries at groups.google.com/group/pyjamas-dev/ are responded to accurately and quickly. A lot of GWT's documentation can be applied and reading the source code can be a help at times too.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe have a look at the GWT JSON RPC [example](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/examples/jsonrpc/).

If that fails, there are always several XML parser implementations in Python AND Java :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your evaluation of Python's text processing and GWT's quality.  Have you considered using Jython?  Googling "pyparsing jython" gives some mixed reviews, but it seems there has been some success with recent versions of Jython.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to this question...

Have you seen this project?

http://code.google.com/p/python-gwt-rpc/

It might be useful as a starting point.